# Swift Version Conditional Compiler

Tags: swift, jenkins

I have a block of code:

```
switch self {
    case let .seconds(s):
        return .interval
    #if swift(>=3.2)
    case .never:
        return .infinity
    #endif
}
```

and it fails to compile with complaint the 'case' label can only appear inside a switch statement.

This is code I have downloaded from a working project, and I'm wondering what setting I have missed.

Whatever missing piece it is, I need to place it in my Jenkins as well so it doesn't get compilation error.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `self`? Show _all_ the coded needed in order for _us_ to compile this (or try to, and get your same error).

Answer (score 2):

`#if` statements cannot guard switch cases. This is considered a [bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4196), although it hasn't been fixed yet. There was a [swift-evolution thread](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20170508/036568.html) for it earlier this year.

It's unclear to me how this can be part of a working project.

Comment: So he'd have to have two switch statements, I guess?

Comment: That's the workaround that the thread initiator on swift-evolution uses. I don't see anything better either.

Comment: For this specific case, using consecutive if statements would work, too.

Comment: down vote? I specifically said, [This is code I have downloaded from a working project, and I'm wondering what setting I have missed.], so no, it's not the 2x switch that I need to write, and wondering what's the piece I'm missing...

Comment: @Arzath, I know what you said, and I would like to challenge you to prove that this project works. My evidence that it cannot work is from the official bug tracker. As far as I can tell, given that you can't build it either, it doesn't look like you have evidence that it does work.

Comment: @Arzath, from your snippet, I'm deducing that your code could be from [ReactiveSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/pull/541/files). However, there never was an `#if` statement around a case.